# How to handle different activities that can be started based on an extra that is pass in?

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity1 and inside this activity I have a button and when it is pressed, it should go to either ActivityA, ActivityB, or ActivityC based on a specific type passed to Activity1.

I currently have a switch statement that handles this, but the issues is when I want to add in an ActivityD, and ActivityE, I would have to change the code again and the switch statement will continue to grow.

What is a better way to do this?

```
    private int type;

    public void onCreate() {
      // ...
      type = getIntent().getIntExtra("type", 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      Intent intent;
      switch (type) {
        case 0:
          intent = ActivityA.newIntent(this);
          break;
        case 1:
          intent = ActivityB.newIntent(this, 1);
          break;
        case 2:
          intent = ActivityC.newIntent(this, "str");
          break;
        default:
          throw new RuntimeException();
      }
      startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: You can change the location this is happening in (and arguably should), but there's no way to avoid someplace running this code, as long as you're using static factory methods.  I would move it into a Router object, but that's as far as you can take it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple fragments in an activity and instead of changing the activity, just replace the fragments, however even with fragments you need to call them.
You also can create multiple views and change the view based on the intents, this method works better with static views.